# Adding time dimension to layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, time

I have a GeoServer installation that is used as a proxy in front of a THREDDS Data Server to be able to add additional metadata to WMS layers (which I haven't found any support for in THREDDS).

I have configured a GeoServer WMS store and added the the WMS GetCapabilities URL to the THREDDS server to the new WMS store. I have then added a layer from the new WMS store to the list of layers from GeoServer.

So far so good. GeoServer can now act as a proxy for the layer in THREDDS.

The problem comes when I try to enable Dimensions for the new layer. I go into edit mode for the layer and then click the "Dimensions" tab. I then enable the "Time" dimension and try to select the correct "Attribute". However no attributes are found in the list and I am not allowed save the new configuration since "Attribute" is a required value.

Any clue to what I can do to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

When not accessing the layers via GeoServer the time dimension works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html#limitations Time (and elevation) are not supported in cascaded WMS layers. Feel free to contribute a patch.

Comment: Read this document in case you decide to work on, or sponsor, this new feature: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer